# Do I have to fully charge Symmetra's Photon Projector?

Tags: overwatch

When playing Symmetra, her alt fire on her Photon Projector allows her to fire an orb. The longer you charge, the larger the orb is.  At max charge, a visual circle fills to a full circle in the center of the screen.  However, you can hold the charge even longer, so this is where I ask my question.

[image]

Do I have to fully charge the Projector, even past the regular circle for those extra seconds I can hold it to maximize damage? or is it once the circle is filled it is at max damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Symmetra In-depth Strategy Guide](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/symmetra.html) by FuriousPaul charging it until the circle is full should be enough to deal max damage.

> When charging up a Photon Orb, it will reach its max charge before the
>   game fires it for you.  This means that you can fire fully charged
>   orbs more often than if you were to wait for the game to fire them for
>   you.  The Orbs will reach max charge when both of the circles in your
>   crosshair meet with each other.  The animation on the right shows when
>   it reaches full charge, but I made it so I waited until the game fired
>   for me:

I also made the same experiences (also for Zenyattas Alternate, btw.) in live games but will try to confirm this in a custom game seeing the damage numbers and edit this answer then.

Comment: I mean visually, there doesn't seem to be a difference, but it always feels like letting the game charge the projectile fully instead of letting go just as it hits max circle makes the projectile penetrate more enemies